# someone is "in/on" high energy

Tags: prepositions, collocations

> I'm so high **on** energy right now. / I'm so high **in** energy right now.
>
> Everyone at the gym is **in** high energy. / Everyone at the gym is **on** high energy.

Which one is correct or are they both correct and natural usage?

Comment: What is the context you are trying to describe? Being "high on ___" has a particular meaning derived from drug effects, but I doubt that is the meaning you want here.

Comment: @Tashus - thank you, I know that "A was high" means A smoked drugs, but then can this expression be used as a joke, or a humorous expression? Cause I saw on television one young celebrity saying this.

Comment: "high on X" can mean that someone simply has a good feeling, *like* the feeling from drugs, but from X instead. It would be odd to say "high on energy" though, unless perhaps someone was drinking an energy drink?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to rephrasing things, as suggested in the other answers, if you want to keep the word *energy*, I would use a different form and preposition:

> I am so **full of** energy right now.
>   Everyone at the gym is **full of** energy.

*Full of energy* is a very common expression.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the initial comments.

For the first one, instead of using

> I'm so high on energy right now.

I think you'd be more likely to hear a native speaker say:

> **I'm so *energetic* right now.**

---

For the second one, instead of using:

> Everyone at the gym is in high energy.

you might be likely to hear this idiom:

> **Everyone at the gym is *in high gear*.**

M-W defines high gear as:

> **high gear** a state of intense or maximum activity — usually used with *into* or *in* : *a project in high gear*.

while Macmillan says:

> **high gear** the state of performing extremely well or extremely quickly

The term *high-gear* isn't necessarily equivalent to "high-energy", but I think they are roughly the same when we are talking about people working out at the gym.

Comment: To be honest "I'm so energized right now" sounds weirder to me than "I'm high on energy." I could see myself saying the latter, it doesent sound too weird to me tbh.

Comment: @bobbin - I think you're right, so I've made an edit. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly common locution "high in energy." That may have altered in some circles to "in high energy," but I have not heard such a usage.

"In high energy engines, heat dispersal is important" is perfectly acceptable, but that usage does not seem to fit your context.

"On high energy settings, Model A uses less power than Model B" is also acceptable, but again that usage does not seem to fit your context.

Because all three locutions are appropriate in some contexts, ngram will not help determine which is currently idiomatic in a specific context. Based on your examples, I think "high in energy" is what you are looking for.