# Filled with energy vs full of energy

Tags: american-english

Is it fine to say "**I'm filled with energy**" instead of **"I'm full of energy"?**

Comment: Related: [High {in/on} energy](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191825/someone-is-in-on-high-energy).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm full of energy.

Is the more commonly used form, that or

> I have lots of energy.

But there is nothing at all wrong with

> I'm filled with energy.

and the meaning is pretty much identical. There are no grammar errors here, nor is this in any way unnatural.